# Sometimes S3 File upload having 0 Bytes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, file-upload

I have a service which takes creates a presigned URL to s3. Currently we donot use contentType to generate the presigned URL but we never had this problem before.

For past some days what we are getting issues are user file uploads are 0 Bytes and getting hard to reproduce as when we try and upload files uisng throttling even its passes through.

Possible root causes we feel are -
Connection Timeout - but our file size is restricted to 25mb.
InternetDropouts - In that case file should not be created
Content Type - Not sure, but then how it. works in our case ? doubting

Can some one shed some light here will be great help

Comment: Amazon S3 [never adds partial objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html) so I would suspect that your client sent zero bytes. You might want to implement [integrity checking](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/) to be sure your client is actually doing what it says it's doing.

Comment: Hey, have you found the root cause? 
We have the same problem when the same file with the same name is pushed to S3 multiple times from multiple threads in parallel. We have versioning enabled and I can see that all of the versions are okay except the last one or the last two. those have 0-byte size.