# AWS CLI - S3 (Cloudian) file uploads Zero bytes of file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I have a *.zip file of size 20 Kb and I'm trying to upload to Cloudian Object Store from AWS CLI. I use the put-object command like below,

```
$./aws s3api put-object --bucket customer-backup-test --key "/database/export/test.zip" --body
 /tmp/test.zip --endpoint-url=https://test.prod.com --ca-bundle ~/cert/ca.crt
```

The upload is successful and I could get the object key after upload, from the console.

After the upload, when I check the size of the file, it is shown as Zero bytes.

```
$./aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://customer-backup-test --endpoint-url=https://test.prod.com --ca-bundle ~/cert/ca.crt | grep test.zip


2022-06-28 07:00:15    0 Bytes /database/export/test.zip
```

To be sure, I've tried uploading multiple valid zip files at multiple instances. Always , I see that the uploaded zip size in S3 to be Zero bytes.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

I've already referred to : [Sometimes S3 File upload having 0 Bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580542/sometimes-s3-file-upload-having-0-bytes)

Update : The target of upload is Cloudian Object Store. Adapted the title and description

Comment: Why are you using an `endpoint-url`? Are you connecting to a non-AWS system? Does it work if you use `aws s3 cp /tmp/test.zip s3://bustomer-backup-test/database/export/ --endpoint-url=https://test.prod.com --ca-bundle ~/cert/ca.crt`?

Comment: Please note that Keys in Amazon S3 should _not_ start with a slash. You should change `"/database/export/test.zip"` into `"database/export/test.zip"`.

Comment: What is `https://test.prod.com`? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: I’m connecting to Cloudian object store (non AWS System). Just updated the details in the question for clarity. I’ll check using cp instead of put-object, as suggested and let you know

Comment: @Marcin: The mentioned URL is the end point of cloudian object store (not AWS S3) . Updated my question with further details.